# How do I aproach this?(for sale, for lease, sold->move something from a category to another)

Tags: loop, customization

First of all, I really apologize for the title of this question.

I'm currently working on a real estate wordpress theme for that will feature ads from the town that I live in.

I basically want to have 3 categories: for sale, for lease and sold and to be able to move let's say a post(house add) from one category to another category.
Each category should have a page where each house that's currently on that category is shown as an excerpt(like the blog index page)

The thing is I don't know how to aproach this? (I'm a beginner developer).

Should I store the house ads in pages or posts. Should I have special page templates?

Could someone give me a set of steps that I need to follow in order to achieve this? (looking for some plain English advice, not code).

Thanks!

Comment: I'd use posts (possibly custom posts, but you may not need them), put them in the appropriate categories, and then use WordPress's built-in category archives (or possibly taxonomy archives, if you're using custom post type & custom taxonomy) to make the listing pages. As to template files -- see [the Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) for a concise look at what file(s) you might need in a theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Pat above - I'd say from my own experience it probably helps in the long run making a Custom Post Type for houses to keep hundreds of the things separate from your main pages (or blog).

For **starting with coding** it all - sometimes to kick off with and starting to learn about these things it will give you a headstart to begin with plugins. I taught myself PHP using the *'trial and error'* method and a local server. So plugins really helped me get to grips with how to write more complicated and personalised code. That and stackexchange & WPSE obviously!

**To help register Custom Post Types** as a beginner I would use something like [Cutsom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) which seems to be the highest rated and most used of the CPT plugins although I have no experience of it myself.

I would then personally **store the data** as post meta and use the `update_post_meta()` [info here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function as I find taxonomies can be tricky and can cause some permalink tantrums with some plugins but it's just a personal thing! But if you're going to be editing them as custom post types anyway it in the `wp-admin` UI area then ignore that function and go the next step.

The next stage would be to get yourself a copy of [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) which I still use to be honest as it saves a bundle of time compared to coding your own metaboxes every time you'd like to spruce the place up a bit. It also gives you nice little php shortcodes to call by in your code like `get_field('house_price')` which you can then pop into a template or page anywhere you like to achieve a nice uniform layout.

To distinguish between the categories in your template then all you need to do is write a simple query. There are hundreds of pages about this, so I'll just put an example (sorry  -  code)

```
    $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'house',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'meta_key' => 'state',
          'meta_value' => 'sold', //Example of the three state of houses you could have as mentioned above.
          'orderby' => 'ID', //choose to order by anything look here [http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters] for more info
          'order' => 'ASC', //to put the oldest posts first - sell em!
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
          );
  $results = new WP_Query($args);
 //    '<pre>'.print_r($results).'</pre>'; // This is a useful line to keep - uncomment it to print all results found - it can then be used to work out if the query is doing the right thing or not.
 while ($results->have_posts()) {
$results->the_post();
the_title();
the_content();
echo '</hr>'; // puts a horizontal line between results
}

wp_reset_postdata(); //re-sets back to normal       

}
```

At the end of the day everyone has a method they prefer or find easier than others so if you're looking to get stuck in the **MOST VALUABLE thing to have is a local server** set up... google MAMP or WAMP (depending on Mac or Windows) and look at some of the methods described to set it up as it means you can have a good play around with anything you're editing (or breaking) before you start pulling apart a live site.

Hope this helps!